# QPixmap scaled aspect ratio is not keep

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

aspectRatioMode=Qt.KeepAspectRatio does not work as expected, or I am getting something wrong

I am tring to open an image and resize it to fit my window, but I need to keep aspect ratio, what I've specified in aspectRatioMode=Qt.KeepAspectRatio, but in fact I get my image resized as it fills whole image_label.size()

```
    def open_image(self, image_path):
        pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.image_label.size(), aspectRatioMode=Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.image_label.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)
        else:
            self.image_label.setText("Failed to load image")
```

Comment: If you're using a QLabel with `scaledContents` set to `True`, it will never work, because that just scales the pixmap to the label size. Note that if you want to provide proper dynamic scaling, it would be easier to use a custom QWidget that paints the image on its own, or consider using the Graphics View framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the line that confused me and which brings to this result

`self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)`

Just needed to remove it and everything works fine